# Co2 k30 sensor not working with Raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, iot, raspberry-pi3

I have following code that is running for detecting CO2 level. 
Below are some of the information about the models.

CO2 sensor - K30 
Raspberry Pi 3

I have done connections between pi and k-30 as per below document 
http://www.co2meters.com/Documentation/AppNotes/AN137-K30-sensor-raspberry-pi-uart.pdf

Below is my python code

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",baudrate =9600,timeout = .5)
print " AN-137: Raspberry Pi3 to K-30 Via UART\n"
ser.flushInput()
time.sleep(1)
for i in range(1,21):

    ser.flushInput()
    time.sleep(1)
    ser.write("\xFE\x44\x00\x08\x02\x9F\x25")
    time.sleep(1)
    resp = ser.read(7)

    high = ord(resp[3])
    low = ord(resp[4])
    co2 = (high*256) + low
    print "i = ",i, " CO2 = " +str(co2)
    time.sleep(.5)
```

I am not getting consistent output.

I am getting something below

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/i2c $ sudo python test-co2.py 
AN-137: Raspberry Pi3 to K-30 Via UART

i =  1  CO2 = 2458
i =  2  CO2 = 2457
i =  3  CO2 = 2448
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test-co2.py", line 16, in <module>
    high = ord(resp[3])
IndexError: string index out of range
pi@raspberrypi:~/i2c $ sudo python test-co2.py 
AN-137: Raspberry Pi3 to K-30 Via UART

i =  1  CO2 = 2207
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test-co2.py", line 16, in <module>
   high = ord(resp[3])
IndexError: string index out of range
pi@raspberrypi:~/i2c $
```

Appreciate any help ?

Comment: You should probably check the result contents before indexing it. Evidently there are less result columns then you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

> high = ord(resp[3])
>
> IndexError: string index out of range

This means the length of the string `resp` is 0 for that particular call and the code is trying to point to the 3rd element of the string. That's why you get an index out of range.

If you try to see the `len(rep)` in every iteration you will get 0 for that particular iteration where the error occurs but as you are having the data in the beginning that means you are at least able to read your serial port.

It's possible the problem lies with the loose connection of the supply/gnd or even RX/TX pins of the sensors.

Can you share what exactly did you do to get data from the serial port of PI3 or try doing: sudo chmod g+r /dev/ttyS0?

Comment: This is 1/2 answer and 1/2 question, please pass only answer, if you need to ask another question you the [ask] interface.